# TortoiseSVN not save the password

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I instaled Tortoise SVN 1.8.7 in Windows 7 Professional 64 bits.

The Tortoise always ask for save the password, but stiling not save :(

I clear path AppData\Roaming\Subversion multiple times, but is not saving anithing on svn.simple

The connection is made by a certificate.

Can anybody tell me me the trick i was missing ? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

When Tortoise SVN was not saving my user/password credentials I solved the problem by going to TortoiseSVN settings -> Saved Data -> Clear Authentication data (see image below). Also check AllowAuthSave is set to true in TortoiseSVN settings -> Advanced.

[image: Clear Authentication Data in TortoiseSVN settings]

If this doesn't work then there may be further set-up required where certificates are involved which I am unfamiliar with.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not to store passwords is set by the Subversion configuration file.

- Right click on your desktop, so you see the TortoiseSVN menu. Go to `TortoiseSVN->Settings`.
- In the *General* section, click on the *Edit* button for the *Subversion Configuration File*.
- Two items you wan to change:

  - Make sure that `password-stores = windows-cryptoapi` is enabled. (I believe this is the default anyway) by removing the `#` in front of the line.
  - Look for the lines that say `store-passwords = no` and `store-auth-creds = no`. Change the `no` to a `yes`, and remove the `#` at the beginning of the line.

Save the changes, and close the initial settings box by clicking on *Ok*. Next time, when Subversion asks for the password, it will store it.

Comment: There are two places where Subversion options are configured (actually three places on Windows). There's the `config` file, there's the `server` file which defines server configurations. In Windows, these values can also be stored in the registry too. Read the svnbook on [Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.layout), especially on the [Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers) configuration. It's possible that a server config is overriding something.

Comment: Check the [Advance Settings](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-registry) on TortoiseSVN. Make sure `AllowAuthSave` is set to true.

Comment: The servers file (in the same directory as the config file) determines this now. In the config file, there are notes about newly deprecated content. If you follow the instructions in this answer, simply read the comments in the file near the settings you wish to change. It'll guide you.

Comment: just be sure not to break the file, I uncommented wrong line accidentally and was not then able to open TortoiseSVN at all. Luckily error was exact and the solution was straightforward ... :-)