# How do I save passwords using svn+ssh with TortoiseSVN without using keys?

Tags: linux, authentication, svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

I can authenticate in the TortoiseSVN client on Windows using passwords only, but it does not remember my password. `TortoisePlink` keeps asking for my password. I prefer not to use keys for the sake of simplicity.

Is this possible? Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN not save the password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797593/tortoisesvn-not-save-the-password)

Comment: @Jakuje: These answers did not work for me.